# How to check type of param class?

Tags: java, android, instanceof

I have the following method:

```
public static String getServiceUri(Class<?> c) {

 // I'd like to check which type the parameter is...
 if(c.getClass().equals(MyClass.class)){
     do stuff 1
 } else {
     do stuff 2
 }
}
```

Invoke method:
`getServiceUri(MyClass.class);`

On `getServiceUri` I want to call a WebService based on the type of a ServiceClass.

I know that equals will compare objects instance, but in this case I'm trying to discover the type of object.

Anyone know how I can compare using this kind of approach?

Answer (score 7):

```
instanceof operator is the best choice..
```

you can do something like this

```
if(c instanceof MyClass){
 //do your stuff

}
```

Comment: instaceof is much better than matching classes as the questionner does. instanceof takes inheritance into account.

Comment: I wish SO allowed you to make one letter fixes like the capital O in instanceOf above.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getServiceUri(Class<?> classParam) {

    if(classParam instanceof MyClass){

     } 
}
```

This is WRONG. It does not even compile because `classParam` needs to be an actual instance(object) to use the instanceof operator: hence the name.

If you want to know if the classParam is exactly equal to MyClass.class:

```
public static String getServiceUri(Class<?> c) {

    if(classParam == MyClass.class){
    }
}
```

However, if you want to check the entire hierarchy of classParam against MyClass then you can do `classParam.isAssignableFrom(MyClass.class)`